# IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am getting in an error when trying to strip off the Domain name within AD.  Here is my code:

```
        string strAccount = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
        string strUserName = strAccount.Split("\\\\".ToCharArray())[1];
        txtStrName.Text = strUserName;

        string selectSQL = "SELECT sAMAccountName, mail FROM ActiveDirectories WHERE mail Is Not Null and sAMAccountName = '" + txtStrName.Text + "'";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = default(SqlDataReader);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();


            txtADName.Text = reader["sAMAccountName"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = reader["mail"].ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
```

It seems to be where I am doing the split.  I can't figure this out.  Can someone help please.  Thanks!!

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: [Exploits Of A Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I think you are right but I can't seem to figure it out.  By taking a look at my code can you see anything I might be doing wrong?  Remind you that this is only happening in IIS 7.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just `"\\"` instead of `"\\\\"`? It looks like you're splitting on 2 backward slashes where it should be just one.

Also, make sure there is more than one item in the resulting array before you try to address the second item.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` may not contains "\" char ?

Answer (score 0):

You access the second item in the split. Are you sure you dont mean [0]?
You should check if it has any elements at all.

```
var elements = strAccount.Split("\\\\".ToCharArray());
var strUserName = elements.Count() > 1 ? elements[1] : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `strAccount` will always be guaranteed to look like "domain\user" your split should look like this:

```
string strUserName = strAccount.Split('\\')[1];
```

You could shorthand checking the desired part of your split (as BartVG pointed out) by using Linq:

```
string strUserName = strAccount.Split('\\').Last();
```

which would simply return the value of strAccount in case it doesn't contain the expected separator char.

Comment: I tried the .Last and now I am receiving only when published in IIS 7 an error stating Invalid attempt to read data when no data is present.  I am very new to IIS 7 and setting up SQL data connections so I do not know what I am doing wrong.  It works fine when I debug it locally but when published I keep getting errors that data is not being connected.  Please help if you can on this matter.

Comment: @sshackles You're facing a different problem that your original question. As far as I can see from your code it's very likely that your database query doesn't return any results. Go ahead and read some tutorials on database queries - just point at `SqlDataReader` and hit `F1` and Visual Studio will take you to the relevant section in MSDN.